# Crypto Mining with PC

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-profitability, ethereum

**I have PC - i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz & graphic: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530**. My Os is Ubuntu. How many Mh/s i could receive for Ethereum? Let's assume the current is free.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MinerGate app Benchmark feature to estimate how fast your PC is.
IMHO it's not possible to generate MH/s on a regular desktop PC. You need a rig to reach that speed. You can have some two-digit hashes, maybe 1 kH/s but no MH/s.